# How to make autocomplete return nid and name?

Tags: 7, ajax

My question is about textfield autocomplete. I have this code:

```
function my_module_menu(){
  $items['my_module/textfield_autocomplete'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'my_module_textfield_autocomplete',
    'file' => '.\my_module\my_module.inc',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access arguments' => array('access example autocomplete'),
  );
  return $items;
}
```

In `my_module.module`:

```
$form['fieldset7-wrapper']['prop'][$i] = array(
          '#type' => 'textfield',
          '#title' => t('Nombre de propietario'),
          // The autocomplete path is provided in hook_menu in ajax_example.module.
          '#autocomplete_path' => 'my_module/textfield_autocomplete'
        );
```

In `my_module.inc`:

```
function inmoges_ofertas_propietario_autocomplete($string) {
  $matches = array();

  // Some fantasy DB table which holds clientes

  foreach ($return as $row) {
    $value = check_plain($row->name).' '.check_plain($row->surname1).' '.check_plain($row->surname2);
    //$value = $row->name.' '.$row->surname1.' '.$row->surname2;
    $matches[$value] = $value;
  }

  // return for JS
  drupal_json_output($matches);
}
```

This works perfect. But I want that json return callback `{nid; name}` instead of `{name,name}`, and also show the name in textfield, but I can save `nid` in my form.

If I change to this my function ajax

```
$matches[$row->nid] = $value;
```

The previous sentence returns `{nid, name}`, but if I choose one value of the list name, in the textfield is shown the `nid` value, not the `name` value.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't have time to flesh out a proper answer but you're looking for the `#value_callback` FAPI property - take a look at the [References module](http://drupal.org/project/references), specifically node reference, at these functions: `node_reference_field_widget_form()` + `node_reference_autocomplete_value()`. That should make it a bit clearer

Comment: Thanks! I'll try! Thanks again! Don't worry your help is apreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [examples module](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples)'s ajax_example_autocomplete.inc file. You'll need to add a validation function that looks up the nid from the node->title:

```
  $result = preg_match('/\[([0-9]+)\]$/', $title, $matches);
  if ($result > 0) {
    // If $result is nonzero, we found a match and can use it as the index into
    // $matches.
    $nid = $matches[$result];
    // Verify that it's a valid nid.
    $node = node_load($nid);
    if (empty($node)) {
      form_error($form['node'], t('Sorry, no node with nid %nid can be found', array('%nid' => $nid)));
      return;
    }
  }
  // BUT: Not everybody will have javascript turned on, or they might hit ESC
  // and not use the autocomplete values offered. In that case, we can attempt
  // to come up with a useful value. This is not absolutely necessary, and we
  // *could* just emit a form_error() as below.
  else {
    $nid = db_select('node')
      ->fields('node', array('nid'))
      ->condition('title', db_like($title) . '%', 'LIKE')
      ->range(0, 1)
      ->execute()
      ->fetchField();
  }
```