# Drupal 7: #autocomplete_path save id to hidden field

Tags: 7, ajax

Basically I have the same problem as described here: [How to make autocomplete return nid and name?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/72658/drupal-7-autocomplete-return-nid-and-name-change-behaviour).

I have a text input with ajax autocomplete:

```
$form['rmanager_id'] = array(
    "#title" => t("Manager"),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#autocomplete_path' => 'members/managers',
    );
```

In `/members/managers` the function is invoked that returns {id => Name} pair. But when I select a name from the drop-down his id is inserted into the textfield. I would like to insert the name there and put the id into a hidden field.

@Clive who commented the previous question didn't give any code samples. I googled, but didn't find anything. Can somebody give a minimal working example to achieve this?